# Open 8080 port on my local server to public

Tags: linux, networking, port

I'm really new to deployment, server management, etc. I'm built this internal dashboard website in my company in port 8080. Other co-workers would like to access my website remotely. Is there a way to open access to public just for port 8080? Please help.

Comment: open the port in firewall

Comment: Related cross site: [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](https://superuser.com/q/284051/178273)

Comment: You could run an nginx server with proper TLS certs ( lookup letsencrypt ) to server some URL  "https://yourcompany.com/yourdashboard"   then in nginx config point location /yourdashboard to your internal port 8080

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how your network is built.

Basically, you have to forward the requests on the port 8080 from the main router connected to the internet to the IP and port of the server hosting the website. This way, every time a request is made to the public IP on the port 8080, the router forwards it to the local IP of the intended server.

If you provide more information about the network infrastructure maybe we could try to figure it out.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you for your input!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to access to Router Property (192.168.1.1) and configure NAT . Other co-workers can access to your website in this way -> publicIp:8080

Comment: Thank you for your answer Francesco!